# Shuttle XPC S113G processor upgrade

Tags: compatibility, processor-socket

I have a Shuttle XPC S113G system.  I need to run 64bit linux and Windows 7 64 bit side by side.  But in order to do that I need a processor that supports VT extensions.

What processor upgrade is recommended and would be compatible with the motherboard?

The current processor is a E5200 Intel dual core at 2.5GHz.

Can I put an E6000 series such as the 6700 CPU into this motherboard? even if the FSB is 1066MHz?  my E5200 is only 800MHz, but the slot is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fine with the 1066 FSB, I think it'll just run the chip at 800 then, but still will be fast but not as fast as it should be.

The sockets are the same, so it's fine.

Comment: Do you need any special bios support for it?

Comment: It is an old processor but if you already have the latest BIOS installed then it should be OK.

Comment: Ok, I think it'll be fine as you say.  Just found out that my motherboard actually supports 1333 FSB natively. So I've purchased a Q8400 which seems to be compatable with this particular shuttle. As it is right now, I have an older processor that is running at 800MHz.